# JQuery does not apply css to selected li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am in the process of making a website and I cannot understand why this js script does not apply the css styling to the li:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var location = window.location;
   var found = false;
   $("#tab-container a").each(function(){
      var href = $(this).attr("href");
      if(href==location){
         $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
         found = true;
      }
   });
   if(!found){
      $("#tab-container li:first").addClass("selected");
   }
});
```

my `li`s are as follows:

```
<head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="basic2.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body background="background.jpg">
        <div id='content'>
                <div id='tab-container'>
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href='a.html'>a</a></li>
                                <li><a href='r.html'>b</a></li>
                                <li><a href='h.html'>c</a></li>
                                <li><a href='c.html'>d</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                <div id='main-container'>
                        <h1>content for page a</h1>
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

The .selected portion:

```
#tab-container ul li.selected {
        border-right: none;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        border-left: 8px solid #006699;
}
```

I do not know js, but I looked at the js code for so long, I think I understand it.

The js portion is from:
http://bobcravens.com/demos/vertical_tabs/html.html

Comment: Have you checked to see if the `selected` class has been added? Most likely the href does not equal to your location var

Comment: `$(this).attr('href')` returns the literal contents of the `href` attribute (as would `this.getAttribute('href')`); not the absolute URL that would be contained within the `href` property (`$(this).prop('href')` or, *better*, `this.href`). And a `document.location` will never be equal to a relative URL (such as all those you use within the `a` elements).

Comment: Yep, you're gonna need a substring of your location and test against that.

Comment: so for example the location of this page and the other tab pages are:
"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/some/folder/a.html". Do i have to include that hole link (upto folder/) for each href?

Comment: Not necessarily, just use `document.location` (as you are) and compare it to `this.href` (or, if you must, `$(this).prop('href')`).

Comment: `href==location` is probably never true.

Comment: @kevinB: could you explain?

Comment: @DavidThomas What you said makes sense, as my actual url will never actually match the href (as it excludes the folders) but when I apply your fix to it, it still does not work. Its as if the html file is not even reading the js portion

Comment: Any errors in your JavaScript console ('F12' in most browsers)?

Comment: " Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined - Anonymous function "

Comment: Then you've (apparently) not included the jQuery library. You'll need to include that.

Comment: @DavidThomas The jQuery library was an issue, but the href also fixed it, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest simplifying your jQuery and using (albeit untested):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // getting a reference to the URL of the current page:
    var location = window.location;

    // selecting all 'a' elements within the '#tab-container' element:
    $('#tab-container a')
    // filtering that collection of 'a' elements, keeping only the element(s)
    // whose 'href' property is equal to the URL of the current page:
    .filter(function(index, DOMNode){
        // index: the index of the node over which we're iterating amongst the
        // collection returned by jQuery,
        // DOMNode: the node itself (could also use, simply, 'this' or '$(this)'):
        return DOMNode.href === location;
    })
    // moving to the parent element of the retained li elements (if any):
    .parent()
    // adding the 'selected' class:
    .addClass('selected');
});
```

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var locationArr = window.location.split("/");
var location = locationArr[locationArr.length - 1];
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand this, but it still does not work

Comment: Can you tell me what it result when you alert the "location" after above line?

Answer (score 1):

It looks work fine.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
   var location = window.location;
   var found = false;
   $("#tab-container a").each(function(){
      var href = $(this).attr("href");
      if(href==location){
         $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
         found = true;
      }
   });
   if(!found){
      $("#tab-container li:first").addClass("selected");
   }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L7PMJ/

Another error may occure on page. Check your console.

Answer (score 1):

`window.location` will give you the full path of your URL; however, the path you are comparing from the anchor tag doesn't contain the domain. You could append it or split the url into an array and compare after the last slash.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var location = window.location;
   var found = false;
   var pArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );


   $("#tab-container a").each(function(){

      var href = $(this).attr("href");

      if(href==pArray[1]){
         $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
         found = true;
      }
   });
   if(!found){
      $("#tab-container li:first").addClass("selected");
   }
});
```